# Configure postfix to send emails per domain from each virtual server

Tags: postfix, smtp, rate-limiting, virtualmin

In my setup I have installed virtualmin for virtual servers. I have following virtual servers with their own dedicated ip address. Postfix is configured as per this [method](https://www.virtualmin.com/documentation/email/dependent) to use dedicated ip for each virtual server.

```
Virtual server 1 (ip = 1.1.1.1) = example.com
virtual server 2 (ip - 2.2.2.2) = example2.com
virtual server 3 (ip = 3.3.3.3) = example3.com
```

My postfix setting in virtualmin already setup to use virtual server's own ip to send emails.
My question is, how to setup following rules of postfix per virtual server.

```
smtp_destination_concurrency_limit = 2
smtp_destination_rate_delay = 1s
smtp_extra_recipient_limit = 10
```

I did not find any configuration like above for per virtual server / per ip rate limiting.